# What are some good safety rules to have when you own a pool?

Tags: safety

What are some fundamental rules that you should have when you own a house with a pool and have young children?

Answer (score 12):

In Australia it is the law that all pools have child safety gates around them. If that's not the case where you are from, I'd strongly suggest investing in one anyway, and being strict about keeping the gate closed.

From [NSW Commission for Children and Young People](http://kids.nsw.gov.au/kids/resources/news.cfm?itemID=6C6286D3081DBF479A794262EC448E30#ixzz1IuGMyUqe)

> Between 1996 to 2005, there were 245
>   children and young people who died as
>   a result of drowning (3.5% of all
>   deaths). 73 of the 245 drowned in
>   private swimming pools or spas.

Teach your children very sternly that they are never to go anywhere near the pool without you, no running, etc., and of course teaching your children how to swim and all about water safety.

And the number of stories I have heard from parents who have just looked away for a moment, and then looked back and their child is in the water is so alarming. If you are supervising your kids, be sure that is exactly what you are doing (not reading a book, or anything else distracting).

Last of all, if you haven't taken a first aid course and learnt CPR, do it. The worst thing imaginable for me would to lose a child when I could have saved them if I had just spent that time to learn CPR.

Comment: +1 for learning CPR. Do everything possible to keep your child out of harms way but when disaster strikes knowing how to handle will save lives.

Comment: +1 for the CPR recommendation.  However, I think a gate is pointless if your children are above a very young age, or if your pool is above-ground and you have the ability to lock or remove the stairs/ladder.  Suggest adding recommendations for: always swim with a buddy, always get an adult's permission before using the pool, never touch the filter inlet while the filter is on, stay out of water over one's head unless a responsible adult is around.

Comment: @HedgeMage - Pool fences & gates put the latch high up on top of one of the poles, and you have to lift it to open. Generally speaking, a 11-12 year old should be able to reach it on tip-toe, but by that age they should have at least passed basic swimming (and if you've had a pool for years and your kids are that age without knowing how to swim properly, it might be time to get them lessons!)

Comment: @Robotnik That varies incredibly.  I've seen them low enough that a 3yo can grab them, and never high enough that my 11yo has to stretch.  I don't doubt that higher latches exist, I just don't accept it as a given.

Comment: +1 for the "pay attention". People who are drowning don't splash or shout like in the movies, they simply disappear under the surface. https://www.webmd.com/parenting/news/20160620/drowning-myths-swimming#1

Answer (score 6):

One thing we tried which works well (assuming your children are old enough to have started to learn to write) was to have the children help write up the **Swimming Pool Rules** on a big piece of card or board. Then they help to fix these rules up somewhere near the pool.

The rules are the common sense things like "no swimming unsupervised", "no fighting" etc.

But the written notice helps them to understand that it's very very important, and having them responsible for creating the notice helps them to commit to it and take it seriously.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need age-appropriate rules, so your children will understand and remember them. For example, "You are not allowed to go swimming without mommy or daddy" for a 3 year old,  or "No horsing around near the pool" for a 6 year old.

Second, sign them up for swimming lessons, unless you're planning to hold them in your arms for the next several years whenever you're in the pool. In the long term, this is how you prevent drowning. Classes for children will emphasize water safety.

Third, CPR is very effective when performed by nurses and paramedics who do it for a living. It is rather less effective when performed by people who took a 2-hour class a few years ago.

Comment: But CPR *performed by people who...* is still a lot better than seeing your child die because you didn't even *attempt* to rescue him/her. If you feel that CPR skills deteriorate over time, take the 2-day class every year!